# Flutter NSException: Configuration fails. It may be caused by an invalid GOOGLE_APP_ID in GoogleService-Info.plist or set in the customized options

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, info.plist, flutter-ios

*GoogleService-Info.plist* file is added via **Add Files to "Runner"** option. So, it is in the Runner directory.

- I had already checked lots of stack overflow answer but unable to figure out the issue.
- I also recheck GOOGLE_APP_ID in GoogleService-Info.plist
- There is no issue in GoogleService-Info.plist configuration.
- I had also added the CFBundleURLTypes attributes below into the [my_project]/ios/Runner/Info.plist file.

  CFBundleURLTypes - CFBundleTypeRole - Editor - CFBundleURLSchemes -**com.googleusercontent.apps.861823949799-vc35cprkp249096uujjn0vvnmcvjppkn**

ISSUE LOG:

```
2020-07-08 09:57:50.535551+0545 Sefyl [63114:5254473] flutter: Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:53595/jh2o62kCyXk=/
2020-07-08 09:57:50.815919+0545 Sefyl [63114:5254485] 6.25.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60501000 started
2020-07-08 09:57:50.851101+0545 Sefyl [63114:5254418] 6.25.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled 
2020-07-08 09:57:50.851571+0545 Sefyl [63114:5254418] 6.25.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS031025] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. To disable screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
2020-07-08 09:57:51.366223+0545 Sefyl [63114:5254423] 6.25.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
2020-07-08 09:57:51.500886+0545 Sefyl [63114:5254426] 6.25.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000004] App with name test does not exist.
2020-07-08 09:57:51.508053+0545 Sefyl [63114:5254426] 6.25.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000009] The GOOGLE_APP_ID either in the plist file 'GoogleService-Info.plist' or the one set in the customized options is invalid. If you are using the plist file, use the iOS version of bundle identifier to download the file, and do not manually edit the GOOGLE_APP_ID. You may change your app's bundle identifier to 'com.sefyl.goflutter'. Or you can download a new configuration file that matches your bundle identifier from https://console.firebase.google.com/ and replace the current one.
2020-07-08 09:57:51.581320+0545 Sefyl [63114:5254055] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.firebase.core', reason: 'Configuration fails. It may be caused by an invalid GOOGLE_APP_ID in GoogleService-Info.plist or set in the customized options.'
*** First throw call stack:
.....
...
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

(lldb)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Finally resolved!**

Simply, Configure the *GoogleService-Info.plist* and *GoogleService.json* according to its platform like:

```
// config acc to platform
final FirebaseOptions firebaseOptions = (Platform.isIOS || Platform.isMacOS)
    ? const FirebaseOptions(
        googleAppID: '1:926446789922:ios:e16***tecf870f0717b',
        gcmSenderID: '2564624562546',
        apiKey: 'AIzaSyChk3KEG7QYrs4kQfg***erwrfCAdgg',
        projectID: 'project-23ff',
        storageBucket: 'gs://project-23ff.appspot.com',
        databaseURL: 'https://project-23ff.firebaseio.com/',
      )
    : const FirebaseOptions(
        googleAppID: '1:926446789922:android:056***f0717b',
        gcmSenderID: '2564624562546',
        apiKey: 'AIzaSyDBq2tJ82wO0RKzfsgu***e6uh3Ko',
        projectID: 'project-23ff',
        storageBucket: 'gs://project-23ff.appspot.com',
        databaseURL: 'https://project-23ff.firebaseio.com/',
      );

final FirebaseApp app =
    await FirebaseApp.configure(name: 'test', options: firebaseOptions);
```

Comment: Where to add these lines?

Comment: Inside void main() async . Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Update :

1st you need to add your
google-info.plist into xcode ,

then

```
main() async{
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
      name: 'RamadanApp',
      options: (Platform.isIOS || Platform.isMacOS)
          ? const FirebaseOptions(
              apiKey: "CHECK VALUE IN INFO.PLIST",
              appId: "CHECK VALUE IN INFO.PLIST",
              messagingSenderId: "CHECK VALUE IN INFO.PLIST",
              projectId: "CHECK VALUE IN INFO.PLIST")
          : const FirebaseOptions(
              apiKey:
                  "CHECK VALUE IN FIREBASE CONSOLE",
              appId:  "CHECK VALUE IN FIREBASE CONSOLE",
              messagingSenderId:  "CHECK VALUE IN FIREBASE CONSOLE"",
              projectId: "CHECK VALUE IN FIREBASE CONSOLE"),
    );

}
```