# How to solve invalid GOOGLE_APP_ID in GoogleService-Info.plist on Flutter Mac?

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, macos, google-play-services

I am trying to run a Flutter project on Xcode Mac (Monterey 12.2) using iPhone SE virtual device - the project builds successfully but when I run, it shows the error status below:

"Exception = NSException *
"Configuration fails. It may be caused by an invalid GOOGLE_APP_ID in GoogleService-Info.plist or set in the customized options." 0x0000600003ed8450"

The app runs superb on Mac's Android Studio (virtual device) .

We have tried:

- cleaning and building the project
- placing plist file properly
- checking Firebase configuration

Also tried the solutions from below link:
[Flutter NSException: Configuration fails. It may be caused by an invalid GOOGLE_APP_ID in GoogleService-Info.plist or set in the customized options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62787686/flutter-nsexception-configuration-fails-it-may-be-caused-by-an-invalid-google)

Your solution would be appreciated. Thanks in advance .